# Add keyboard switcher to stalonetray

Tags: keyboard-layout, rc

I am running xmonad on top of your average Ubuntu installation. In xmonad, I run stalonetray to handle wifi. This is my `.xsessionrc`:

```
stalonetray & nm-applet &

exec xmonad
```

How do I add Ubuntu's keyboard layout switcher to it? (or any other would be fine).